# Java leap year logic error

Tags: java, date

Here is my code for testing if a date is valid for the month of February. The top part for testing if a leapYear is true or false works properly. If I input for example 02/29/1963 as a date, leapYear will = false. Yet for some reason the code will continue as if leapYear = true. The end result would be:

```
else if (leapYear = true){
    if ((day > 0) && (day < 30) && (month ==2)){
        System.out.println("Your date is valid.)"`
```

it will output "Your date is valid." whereas it should output specifically for the date 02/29/1963 "Your date is invalid because there are only 28 days in February for the year 1963.");

I cannot figure out why it is doing this. Thanks for your time.
RESOLVED

```
if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) {
    leapYear = true;
} else {
    leapYear = false;
}

if (leapYear = false) {
    if ((day > 0) && (day < 29) && (month == 2)) {
        System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
    } else if (day > 29) {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 28 days in February"
                        + "for the year " + year + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
    }
} else if (leapYear = true) {
    if ((day > 0) && (day < 30) && (month == 2)) {
        System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
    } else if (day > 30) {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 29 days in February for"
                        + "the year " + year + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: try if (leapYear == false) and instead of (leapYear = false)

Comment: As a stylistic thing, you should almost never compare a boolean to a literal `true` or `false`. Rather than `if (a == true)` or `if (b == false)`, just do `if (a)` or `if (!b)`. The `if` is _already_ comparing the boolean to true or false; you don't need to re-state that comparison. Or, to put it another way: you wouldn't usually write `if ( (i == 3) == true)` to compare i to 3, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` and `else-if` condition must not be [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operation rather [comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Instead of `if (leapYear = false){` try

```
if (leapYear == false){
```

or just

```
if (!leapYear){
```

Same for `else if (leapYear = true){`. It will be

```
else if (leapYear == true){
```

or

```
else if (leapYear){
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use assignment operator in `if` statement. You have to do a equality check :

```
 if (leapYear == false) {
        if ((day > 0) && (day < 29) && (month == 2)) {
            System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
        } else if (day > 29) {
            System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 28 days in February"
                            + "for the year " + year + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
        }
    } else if (leapYear == true) {
        if ((day > 0) && (day < 30) && (month == 2)) {
            System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
        } else if (day > 30) {
            System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 29 days in February for"
                            + "the year " + year + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize you can't use this for your homework, but FYI for others, Java includes this feature in its [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
Year year = Year.from ( now );
Boolean isLeap = year.isLeap ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "year: " + year + " isLeap: " + isLeap );
```

When run.

> year: 2015 isLeap: false

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (leapYear == false) {
    if ((day > 0) && (day < 29) && (month == 2)) {
        System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
    } else if (day >= 29) {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 28 days in February"
                        + "for the year " + year + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
    }
} else if (leapYear == true) {
    if ((day > 0) && (day < 30) && (month == 2)) {
        System.out.println("Your date is valid.");
    } else if (day > 30) {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because there are only 29 days in February for"
                        + "the year " + year + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your date is invalid because the day you entered does not exist.");
    }
}
```